# How to convert irregular datetime to total seconds in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have a column of duration but the values are different. Some duration are only time format and some have mixed with date. I want the duration column in total seconds. I tried to convert the column with to_datetime and parse_date methods but it cannot work. How to do this in pandas? Here is the column:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihetf.png)

Comment: "but it cannot work..". Show your code that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["03:59:49", "04:59:49", "1904-01-01 05:59:49", "1904-01-01 06:59:49"]})
df["TotalSeconds"]  = pd.to_timedelta(df["a"].str.extract('(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})')).dt.total_seconds()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                     a  TotalSeconds
0             03:59:49       14389.0
1             04:59:49       17989.0
2  1904-01-01 05:59:49       21589.0
3  1904-01-01 06:59:49       25189.0
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, it works. But there are some NaN values, how to delete or convert it to 0.

Comment: You can use `df.fillna(0)`

Comment: Ex: `pd.to_timedelta(df["a"].str.extract('(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})')).dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `pd.Series.apply` with a `try` / `except` clause, which attempts each method sequentially.

The benefit of this method is that it will accept a wide range of potential inputs for `timedelta` and `datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Mixed': ['03:59:49', '1904-01-01 04:06:08']})

def return_seconds(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_timedelta(x).total_seconds()
    except:
        try:
            dt = pd.to_datetime(x)
            return (dt - dt.normalize()).total_seconds()
        except:
            return np.nan

df['TotalSeconds'] = df['Mixed'].apply(return_seconds).astype(int)

print(df)

#                  Mixed  TotalSeconds
# 0             03:59:49         14389
# 1  1904-01-01 04:06:08         14768
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter last 8 values, convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then use [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['03:59:49', '1904-01-01 04:06:08']})

df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'].str[-8:]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                   col    new
0             03:59:49  14389
1  1904-01-01 04:06:08  14768
```

EDIT:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Comment: When I pass the original Pandas Series from the DataFrame 'data' as data['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Finish_Netto'].str[-8:]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)   then it show error as "ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format"

Comment: @MAK - It seems there is some another format of data, so please check edited answer.

Comment: the data is a DataFrame and column type is object. Now it gives another error as: " TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime"